# Relation of Class numbers and Special Values of zeta functions

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, zeta-functions

I am reading Serre's article on p-adic Modular forms  (Formes modulaires et fonctions zˆeta p-adiques).

In section 1.6, Serre constructs p-adic Eisenstein series by considering

$G_{k_i} = \frac{1}{2}\zeta(1-k_i) + \sum_{n \geq 1} \sigma_{k_i-1}(n) q^n$

such that $k_i$ converge to $k$ in $X = \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$ with $|k_i|_{\infty}$ tending to infinity.

This sequence of q-expansions converge p-adically and thus we arrive at a p-adic Eisenstein series. Hence, for a fixed $k \in X$ we have been able to define a p-adic Eisenstein series.

Following this, Serre provides one specific example.

Let $p \equiv 3 (mod.4)$ and let $k = (1,\frac{p+1}{2}) \in X$, then by previous procedure we get a p-adic Eisenstein series which is

$\frac{1}{2}h(-p) + \sum_{n \geq 1} \sum_{d|n} (\frac{d}{p}) q^n$

where $h(-p)$ denotes the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$.

I think I can figure out the coefficients of $q^n$ for $n \geq 1$ but I have no clue about the constant term. How do we get this?

And I feel this is due to my lack of knowledge about "some relation between special values of zeta and class numbers".

Comment: For what it’s worth, the “limit” Eisenstein series is a classical Eisenstein series $E$ of weight one for $\Gamma_1(p)$ (and the constant term is a bit easier to find out – with analytic continuation and the analytic class number formula). I don’t really know how this works on the $p$-adic side, though. Here’s the sketch of an idea (relying on something that I think Serre proves): $E^2$ is a weight $2$ modular form for $\Gamma_0(p)$, so is a $p$-adic modular form in his sense. Now compare its $q$-expansion with the square of the limit of the $E_{1+(p-1)p^n/2}$ (assuming it exists…)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda: (\mathbb{Z}/p)^{\times} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ be the  unique character of order two.

Consider, for $s \in \mathbb{C}$, the series $E_s(\tau)=\sum_{p \mid c}{\frac{y^{s-1}\lambda(d)}{(c\tau+d)|c\tau+d|^{2(s-1)}}}$, for $\tau \in \mathbb{H}$. It is absolutely convergent for $Re(s) >>0$, smooth as a function of $\tau$ and holomorphic with respect to $s$.

Its Fourier expansion can be explicitly computed for $Re(s)>>0$ and meromorphically continued to $\mathbb{C}$ with some explicit bounds. Since $E_s$, while not holomorphic, transforms under $\Gamma_0(p)$ like an element of $\mathcal{M}_1(\Gamma_1(p),\lambda)$, we see that $E_s$ has meromorphic continuation to $s \in \mathbb{C}$, with an explicit Fourier expansion, and it still transforms in the same way.

It can be checked in particular with the analytic class number formula (probably in eg Neukirch’s *Algebraic Number Theory*) that $E_1(\tau)$ is proportional to $E(\tau) := \frac{h(-p)}{2} +\sum_{n \geq 1}{\sum_{d \mid n}{\lambda(d)}q^n}$, hence $E(\tau) \in \mathcal{M}_1(\Gamma_0(p),\lambda)$.

(The computation above should be carried out in more detail in most texts about classical modular forms, eg Diamond-Shurman or Miyake, making the connection to the analytic class number formula more apparent).

In particular, $E^2 \in \mathcal{M}_2(\Gamma_0(p))$, so it is a $p$-adic modular form in the sense of Serre.

Let $F$ be the $p$-adic limit of the $G_{1+(p-1)p^n/2}$ (it exists, by Corollaire 2, p. 204). It’s not too hard to see that in $\mathbb{Z}_p[[q]]$, $E-F$ is a constant $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ (see 4), p. 208). But of course, $E$ has no $p$-adic meaning (while $F$ is purely $p$-adic).

However, $E^2,F^2$ are $p$-adic modular forms of weight $2$, and $E^2-F^2=\alpha (E+F)=\alpha (2F+\alpha)$. If $\alpha \neq 0$, it follows that $2F+\alpha$ is a $p$-adic modular form of weight $2$.

Reducing mod $p$, the contradiction follows from the previous results of Swinnerton-Dyer (see the bottom of p. 196).